# How can I change this MaraiDB bulk insertion code into Postgres without mapping each column and property?

Tags: postgresql

There is a dynamic method in our codebase that inserts a list of entities into a specified table in MariaDB:

```
    public List<string> BulkInsert(List<T> entities)
    {
        var problems = new List<string>();
        var table = entities.ToTable();
        var connectionString = ConnectionString;
        if (!connectionString.Contains("AllowLoadLocalInfile"))
        {
            connectionString = $"{connectionString};AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;";
        }
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.InfoMessage += (s, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in e.Errors)
            {
                problems.Add(item.Message);
            }
        };
        connection.Open();
        var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName;
        try
        {
            var result = bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            return problems;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
            Logger.LogError(problems.Merge());
            throw new ServerException(ex.Message + ". See the logs for the list of problems. Also make sure your database schema, specially column orders is correct. And make sure that you use FakerHelper for correct formatting.");
        }
    }
```

Basically this method (which is part of the base repository class) uses a connection string, a table name, and a list of entities and uses `MySqlBulkCopy`.

For example, I can give the `CustomerRepository` which inherits the `Repository` a `List<Customer>` and it inserts it all in bulk, and reports problems of records that could not be inserted.

I want to change it to Postgres, but I'm stuck at this point that almost all examples that I see (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65687071/bulk-insert-copy-ienumerable-into-table-with-npgsql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250053/bulk-insert-c-sharp-dataset-to-aws-postgresql)) include a mapping of properties to columns one by one.

I'm new to Postgres. Is there a method that takes a data table and matches it with a target table automatically?